# Textbox value is not getting changed on assigning it to a value in the c# code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

This is the code for my Textbox (DepartureDateTB):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DepartureDateTB"
             runat="server"
             CssClass="DepartureDateTB"
             ClientIDMode="Static"
             ontextchanged="DepartureDateTB_TextChanged"
             EnabledViewState="False"
             AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1"
                      runat="server"
                      ControlToCompare="ArrivalDateTextBox"
                      ControlToValidate="DepartureDateTB"
                      ErrorMessage="*Departure to be greater"
                      ForeColor="Red"
                      Operator="GreaterThan">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

JQuery for Date Picker:

```
$(function () {
            $("[id$='DepartureDateTB']").datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: "+30D" });
            $("[id$='DepartureDateTB']").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");

    });
</script>
```

On Page load, I am assigning a value to the textbox from database.

Then when the user changes it, there's a postback but the changed value is not retained.

Even when I tried assigning a Session variable to it and then equate it, all I get is an empty textbox.

```
Session["DepDateTB"] = (Request.Form[DepartureDateTB.UniqueID]).ToString();
                DepartureDateTB.Text = Session["DepDateTB"].ToString();
```

And when I position a break point and run it, when I hover over the Textbox the value of it is the changed date but the textbox in the front end is again empty.

Comment: You must have not included `!IsPostBack` in your `Page_Load` event. Included one and inside it add Initial data.

Comment: My initial data is getting added. It's only the changed data that is not appearing on postback.

Comment: Change EnabledViewState="True", if that helps ? BTW why it is false ?

Comment: @Dot_NETPro Even when it is true, the issue persists.

Comment: Please post all your Page_Load code

Answer (score 1):

The reason the date wasn't getting displayed was due to the following line in the jQuery code:

```
$("[id$='DepartureDateTB']").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```

Once the date format option was removed it worked fine.

I resorted to changing the date format in my c# code.